# HMSegmented Control Error "attempt to insert nil object from objects[0] "when Use Custom Font

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uisegmentedcontrol

I am NewBie in iOS Development.I use [HMSegmentedController](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl)For my Application.In My Application SegmentedControll Section Titles in Gujarati like as

```
self.segmentedControl.sectionTitles = @[@"નવું", @"જાણવા જેવું"];
```

Now I want to Set this Font to My Custom Font like as

```
self.segmentedControl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"NotoSansGujaratiUIRegular" size:6.0f];
```

when i set it to Custom Font then it give me error as

```
[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

And i run without Custom Font then it run as i want but i want to set it Custom Font Please Give me Solution For it.

Here I added UIKIt in My Framework And Also Added in info.plist file as

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>NotoSansGujaratiUIRegular.ttf</string>
        <string>NotoSansGujaratiUIBold.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

Please Give me Solution For this.

Comment: NSLog [UIFont fontWithName:@"NotoSansGujaratiUIRegular" size:6.0f]

Comment: @SidShah when i Log all Font in ViewDidLoad then It Shows NotoSansGujaratiUIRegular in font.